# Does the adobe 'Alchemy' support the posix pthread library?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, alchemy

When I use pthread_create function create a thread in the c code, it fails.

But, the pthread.h in the avm2-lib directory is declared pthread_* functions.

I want to know whether the 'Alchemy' support thread.

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy transforms C code into ActionScript one. So, its capabilities are limited, no system access, no threads. Basically, its for arithmetics only.

Comment: Using the ASync_* function of Alchemy may be could simulate the pthread_* features.